# Why do i have to create my thread in another class, to avoid freezing my Tkinter UI?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a Tkinter application, in which I have a button, calling a function. To avoid freezing the UI, while this function processes, I'm starting it within its own thread.

If I spawn the thread within the same class, as the method I'm calling is defined, my UI still freezes. The only way I have been able to fix this is by creating a *Threader* class, whose sole purpose, is to call a function within a new thread.

I have tried shaving down my *app* class, to only the relevant things, for this problem, but let me know if you are suspecting that I cut away too much:

```
from threader import Threader
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
                ...
                self.run_btn=ttk.Button(self, text='Run', command=self.start_clicked, width=15)
                self.Threader = Threader()
                ...
        
        def start_clicked(self):
                Thread(target=self.my_func()).start() # this freezes my ui 
                # self.Threader.run_thread(self.my_func()) # this does not freeze my ui


        def my_func(self):
                # some logic
```

This is my *Threader* class:

```
from threading import Thread

class Threader:

    def run_thread(self, name, func):
        Thread(target=func).start()
```

In my *App* class I have included both ways I have tried spawning the thread, within the *start_clicked* function. The first one is the one freezing my UI, and the one commented-out, in which I spawn the thread, through my *Threader* class, is the one which doesn't.

In my mind, there shouldn't be a difference, so I can't figure out why one works, and the other doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `()` at `Thread(target=self.my_func).start()` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud no I have not, and it seemed to solve my problem. The answer from Bryan Oakley even explains why. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
Thread(target=self.my_func()).start()
```

Functionally, it is exactly the same as this:

```
result = self.my_func()
Thread(target=result).start()
```

See the problem? You are immediately calling `self.my_func()` in the current thread.

The `target` needs to be a *reference* to a function:

```
Thread(target=self.my_func)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! 
It seems quite obvious when you put it like that.